# Parse migration heroku

Tags: ios, rest, heroku, parse-platform, migration

Guys I need help with parse migration. My parse was created in heroku and now I'm trying to call parse via REST

> Request for class xx failed with error: Error
>   Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1011 "Expected status code
>   in (200-299), got 403" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Expected
>   status code in (200-299), got 403,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://sheltered-**et-*****.herokuapp.com/parse/classes/xx}

Something with credentials?

I tried several configurations but without luck

index.js

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId:  '123456789',
  clientKey:'123456789',
  masterKey: '123456789'
});
```

ios:

```
//static NSString * const kSDFParseAPIBaseURLString = @"https://api.parse.com/1/";
    static NSString * const kSDFParseAPIBaseURLString = @"https://sheltered-hamlet-****.herokuapp.com/parse/";
    static NSString * const kSDFParseAPIApplicationId = @"123456789";
    static NSString * const kSDFParseAPIKey = @"123456789";
    - (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
        self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
        if (self) {

            [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
            [self setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"X-Parse-Application-Id" value:kSDFParseAPIApplicationId];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key" value:kSDFParseAPIKey];value:kSDFParseAPIKey];



        }

        return self;

}

sharedClient = [[SDAFParseAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kSDFParseAPIBaseURLString]];
```